# Duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering, say if a question `X` is waiting without any answer , if we ask another question alike that one, is this count duplicate? Because on duplicates it says: “This question may already have an answer here” and that question `X`  is not answered.

Comment: Seems like a paradox

Comment: Why do you ask the same question that has not been answered ?

Comment: @Outofmemory There is lots of questions waiting without any answer most of them are old. So we should wait untill someone give an answer? It's not smarty.

Comment: You can't close a question that doesn't have an answer as a duplicate unless it was asked by the same person.  My gut feeling is that if someone creates a verbatim duplicate question, that's not cool; if the new question has similar but more details, I'm okay with it.

Comment: @Navi If the question has not been answered for a long time, then make a reference of that question in your present question, the question. `is this count duplicate?` no it is not a count duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible that decent, answerable questions randomly fall through the cracks. It may have been posted at a time when nobody versed in the topic was looking at the site, or it may have been posted at rush hour when there was too much activity, or it may not have had an interesting enough title, or may have had the wrong tags etc. etc. Eventually the question vanishes from the top of the stack (pardon the pun) and is forgotten and never found by anyone.

If you stumble upon such a question and it is an absolute, exact duplicate of what you were going to ask yourself, please direct your effort towards resurrecting that old question instead of posting yet another one with essentially the same content.

You can:

1. offer a bounty for the question (though only if you have enough reputation)
2. edit the question to be better (better tags, better title, more information); this also bumps the question back to the front page
3. promote the question (share a link on Twitter, some forum, via email, paste it in the appropriate chatroom with a plea for help)

Doing any of these things should typically help direct the necessary attention to the question. You can keep an eye on the question's view count to confirm that it is getting enough exposure. If it receives more expose but still no answers, it may not be clear enough, in which case you can edit it again to be better. If that still doesn't help, it may simply be an unanswerable or extreme niche question, in which case any duplicate shouldn't fare any better.